# ASP.NET MVC application is attempting a GET request on a POST only method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7 web application which is getting a 404 HTTP code.

> System.Web.HttpException: at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction (System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)

The application is hosted in Azure and the error is only occurring for some of the end users, not everyone. I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to recreate this error in any test environment which also resides in Azure. Has anyone encountered this issue before and how were you able to resolve it ? The application receives this error when attempting to execute GET Surveys/Submit when only a POST Surveys/Submit is present in the code. I understand that the HTTP 404 is because the GET method doesn't exist. My question is what would cause the attempted execution of the GET when it is not coded anywhere to perform that request ?

This is my controller / action method which is decorated with the HttpPost attribute:

```
public class SurveysController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit()
    {
        try
        {
            // some stuff...     
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Code from my .cshtml:

```
<form id="survey" role="form" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Submit", "Surveys")">
```

RouteConfig

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds silly but try making post all uppercase (method= "POST")

Comment: Also what are you POST'ing? your controller method doesn't accept any arguments `Submit(?)`

Comment: Attempting to GET a POST method should return an error 405 Method Not Allowed, not error 404 Not Found. Is there anything that sets apart the users that are getting the error?

Comment: The application is POSTing responses to a Survey (HTTP form) by using the Request.Form object from the System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper. The POST method does work. The issue is when on occasion the application will attempt a request using route GET Surveys/Submit which doesn't exist and hence the 404 Http response code.